# How to append to the bottom row of two columns of a csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a function that basically returns the date today and a random integer to the bottom of their respective columns each time the function is called.

```
def date_to_csv():
    import pandas as pd
    from random import randint
    df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
    df['Date'] = [datetime.date.today()]
    df['Price'] = [randint(1,100)]
    df.to_csv('test.csv',mode='a',index=False,header=None)
```

For the first two time the function is called it works as expected and returns this in the csv file:

```
Date,Price
2021-06-26,29
2021-06-26,97
```

However calling the function afterwards returns an error: 'ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)'

I plan to call the function for a n number of consecutive days on the same csv file.

Comment: clearly is will `[datetime.date.today()]` is an array of length 1, which you are trying to assign to a dataframe that has two rows.  Hence length mismatch...  you say you want to append,  therefore use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")    
df = df.append({'Date':datetime.date.today(), 'Price':randint(1,100)})
df.to_csv('test.csv',mode='a',index=False,header=None)
```

Comment: It returns an errors: "TypeError: Can only append a dict if ignore_index=True" and when you add ignore_index=True it starts mutiplying the results. Running your code 3 times with ignore_index set to true this is what it returns when it should only return 3 rows.                                                                                  Date,Price
"[datetime.date(2021, 6, 26)]",60
"[datetime.date(2021, 6, 26)]",60
"[datetime.date(2021, 6, 26)]",74
"[datetime.date(2021, 6, 26)]",60
"[datetime.date(2021, 6, 26)]",60
"[datetime.date(2021, 6, 26)]",74
"[datetime.date(2021, 6, 26)]",100

Comment: edited, even if square parentheses wasn't the main error, this shoud work better.
Really don't know why it print twice on the dataframe, try to check how many times the function get called (with a simple print) for every run

Answer (score 0):

as Rob Raymond said.you today list and random list is not match you csv length.so you should make them match.and every time you write to_csv.the mode is `a` which is append new row to it.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
length = df.shape[0]
df['Date'] = [datetime.date.today() for _ in range(length)]
df['Price'] = [randint(1,100) for _ in range(length)]
df.to_csv('test.csv',mode='a',index=False,header=None)
```

only append new row after each run

```py
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df = df.append({'Date':datetime.date.today(), 'Price':randint(1,100)},ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('test.csv',mode='w',index=False)
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[datetime.date.today()], 'Price':[randint(1,100)]})
df.to_csv('test.csv',mode='a',index=False,header=None)
```

```py
with open('test.csv','a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([datetime.date.today(),randint(1,100)])
```

Comment: Just like previous answers your code works as well but now it makes duplicates each time you run the function when in fact I only want to add one row for each time I call the func.

Comment: @buckenup you didn't mention  you want to add one row for each run in the question.I supply 3 solution.pick whichever you want